# Why spring integration doc for akka exists only for 1.3.1 but not for next versions

Tags: java, spring, integration, akka

There is a link about the way to integrate `AKKA` and `Spring`. Or better say: "how to use `Akka` actors in `spring` environment".

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-modules/1.3.1/modules/spring.html

Actually there is `modules` folder http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-modules/ that exists only for `1.3.1` version.

```
Does it mean that there is no integration for different than `1.3.1` version 
 with spring? 
Or it means that we should not use it (spring integration I mean)? 
Or we should do it in the same way as we do it for `1.3.1` version?
```

Comment: Probably because the people at Typesafe did not value that module going forward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `akka-spring` module was not ported to the Akka 2.x series because it conflicts with the way actor systems work: with parental supervision only actors create other actors, which means that Spring—not being an actor—cannot create actors.

There is a new section in the documentation for the upcoming 2.2 release about how to use dependency injection while creating actors (see [the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0-RC1/java/untyped-actors.html#Creating_Actors_with_Factory_Methods)). We are working on a more complete document describing the interplay between DI frameworks and Akka.

Answer (score 4):

As pointed out by Roland Kuhn, you keep the creation of child actors within their parents otherwise you lose the whole concept of supervision.

There is a useful post here: http://blog.nemccarthy.me/?p=272 on two approaches in 2.2 on wiring up Akka Actors with Spring using the `IndirectActorProducer`.

Prior to 2.2 you could also use the `UntypedActorFactory` to do a similar thing. The `IndirectActorProducer` is a much cleaner way to do this. You could also look at `Creator`: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.0-RC1/index.html#akka.japi.Creator

Comment: [This](https://github.com/sabomichal/akka-java-springfactory) implementation should satisfy both worlds, since it is a Spring factory and it is using mentioned `Creator` API.