# Akka Camel and Spring

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, akka

I want to combine Akka, Apache Camel, Spring and do not know the way forward for leveraging the three things in the same project.

I was successfully able to

```
1. write some working code with akka, akka-camel extension and camel routes(Java DSL)
2. use camel and spring (use java DSL but spring for transactions and etc..)
```

Now I need to combine 1 and 2. Can anyone suggest me the simplest way to achieve this?

**EDIT**
Some say AKKA no longer supports Spring due to conflict in object instantiation as per the link below
[Why spring integration doc for akka exists only for 1.3.1 but not for next versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948292/why-spring-integration-doc-for-akka-exists-only-for-1-3-1-but-not-for-next-versi)

Also a similar question is there without a proper solution being presented but the post is about 2 years old
[akka-camel 2.2.1 route definition using Spring XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19306531/akka-camel-2-2-1-route-definition-using-spring-xml?rq=1)

In one blog post (which I can't get hold of the link right now) a method has been described which is in summary, the actors are defined and used Akka way and what ever the processing Akka actors does to be wired using Spring. But there wasn't any solid example.

Comment: Who ever tempted to down vote, mind if you add a comment also as to say why you are down voting. The comment could be damn helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine your #2 looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd >

  <!-- Camel route configuration -->
    <camelContext id = "testCamelRouteContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="test_data_webservice">
            <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8888/myTestService"/>
            <log logName="HTTP LOG" loggingLevel="INFO" message="HTTP REQUEST: ${in.header.testdata}"/>
            <process ref="myTestService"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>

    <context:annotation-config />

    <bean class="com.package.service" id="myTestService"/>

        <bean id="genericDao" class="com.dao.Impl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="testingDataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        datasource stuff
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Is it possible that you can get this camel context through Akka?  Something like.

Add in your Akka config:

```
akka.camel.context-provider="myNewContext"
```

New ContextProvider class:

```
class myNewContext extends ContextProvider{
    override def getContext(system: ExtendedActorSystem): SpringCamelHybridContext
}
```

I am guessing this is where the bean injection collision between Spring and Akka could occur.  I have never used Akka before so my answer is trivial but I wanted to see if I could provide some help to you.

Answer (score 0):

Reviving an old thread.

[akka-springctx-camel](https://puspendubanerjee.github.io/akka-springctx-camel/) library is there to make your life painless to integrate Akka, Spring, Camel, CXF etc.

Add artifact :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.PuspenduBanerjee</groupId>
   <artifactId>akka-springctx-camel</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Add Camel Context Provider in Akka config:

```
akka.camel.context-provider=system.SpringCamelContextProvider
```

Get hold of ActorSystem :

```
implicit val system = SpringContextActorSystemProvider.create
```

Create a custom RouteBuilder[other way could be Akka Consumer]

```
class CustomRouteBuilder(system: ActorSystem, echoActor: ActorRef)
  extends RouteBuilder {
  def configure {
    from("direct:testEP")
      .routeId("test-route")
      .to(echoActor)

  }
```

Get Camel(Spring) Context and add routes to it:

```
val camel = CamelExtension(system)
    camel.context.addRoutes(
         new CustomRouteBuilder(system, system.actorOf(Props[EchoActor])))
```

This test case will give you a detailed idea: https://github.com/PuspenduBanerjee/akka-springctx-camel/blob/master/src/test/scala/AkkaSpringCtxTestSpec.scala